# Spring Boot MVC application war file deployed on Tomcat8 failing with java.lang.TypeNotPresentException

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, tomcat8

I wrote a REST API with Spring Boot and packaged it as a WAR file. I copied the WAR to Tomcat 8's `webapps` folder and started tomcat service. While the server was starting up, it throws some exceptions caused by:

> java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type
>   org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration not present

I played around the problem a bit and discovered that if I moved the the JAR files on the webapp's lib, and lib-provided folders to Tomcat8/lib folder, no exceptions are thrown and the API works as expected. I don't know what's causing the problem. I have a few dependencies on my `pom.xml` with their scope as `provided`. Maybe they are causing me the problem.

Here's my pom:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pp</groupId>
        <artifactId>DAO-Commons</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pp</groupId>
        <artifactId>carddao</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pp</groupId>
        <artifactId>cardtemplatedao</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pp</groupId>
        <artifactId>cardlibrarydao</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Keep the `provided` scope for `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` and remove it form others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [maven docs - dependency mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

Try removing the scope provided! They will be available on WEB-INF/lib dir within your war.